# can i use 12v battery while charging?

Tags: batteries, charger, 12v

hello guys i have 70AH 12V battery and i have triple phase charger can charge from (0 to 140 ah batteries ) the chager turn off automatically when the battery full charge and i have 12V to 220 V inverter the problem is that i play lots of mmo games and in games like League of legend i cant disconnect even for 1 min ( if i did my team will lose and if i disconnect for more then 5 m i will get ban ) my internet is very good but my problem is with the electricity it cut off any time suddenly so can i do what i did in the photo??
i don't want to disconnect when the electricity  cuts off so i want to plug my internet cable to the inverter while I'm playing only is that OK?

[image]
[image]

the battery was full so it give only about 1 amp (the load is about 90 watt) and i put the charger on the 80ah ( instead of 70ah because of the load is that ok?? ) thx guys a :)

thx alot

Comment: It is generally recommended that lead-acid batteries should not be charged at more than 1/4 C (where C is 70 Amps, for your 70AH battery), so you should limit the maximum charging current to under 20 Amps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be OK. It is how most [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) (Uninterruptible Power Supplies)
work. If nothing gets too hot then this should work fine.